# How to use data item in ListView - Android Studio

Tags: android, mysql, listview, android-listview, baseadapter

I'm developing an Android app (using Android Studio) which is able to display a ListView with items from my Database. To do that I'm using JSon with Volley library.

To display my ListView, we need to do a research (via a basic search bar). This research allow me to display the username and user id from my User table in my Database.

This works fine.

I'm using a `CustomListAdapter` with a `BaseAdapter` extension.

Now, what I want to do is to work with the user_id specific to each item.
I did a lot of research about this problem but I still don't know how to deal with it.

Here's my `CustomListAdapter.class`

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Activity activity;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private List<User> usersItems;
private Context context;


public CustomListAdapter(Activity activity, Context cont, List<User> users_Items) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.usersItems = users_Items;
    this.context = cont;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return usersItems.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int location) {
    return usersItems.get(location);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (inflater == null)
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null)
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_user, null);

    final TextView user_name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.username);
    final TextView id = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.id);

    ImageButton add = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button_add);


    User u = usersItems.get(position);
    user_name.setText(u.getUsername());
    id.setText(String.valueOf(u.getUserID()));

    // "add" button is pressed
    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                    activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {


                            Toast.makeText(context, "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                        }
                    });

                }


            }).start();
        }


    });

    return convertView;

    }
}
```

I want to work with the user_id when the add button is clicked. In a first step, I just want to display the user_id to the specific item in a Toast instead of the "Hello" I put in.

Comment: "I want to work with the user_id" -- meaning what? You have a `User` object, does it have an id? You also shouldn't create a separate `OnClickListener` for every row in `getView()`. You should use an `OnItemClickListener` on the ListView instead.

Comment: just a tip, `getView` already runs on the UI thread so you dont need `runOnUiThread` in there to show a toast

Comment: Karakuri, I want to stock the user_id of the selected item in a table of my Database (Not the User table, an other one). Ok I'll try for the OnItemClickListener. Thanks for the tip tyczj.

Comment: Thank you Karakuri. Your advice helpd.